# How do I provide a list of functions in Racket?

Tags: racket

If I have a function that I want to be available outside of the current module, I can do the following...

```lisp
(provide my-function)
```

Can I do this for a list of functions?

I tried the following...

```lisp
(define f1 ...) ; body omitted for clarity
(define f2 ...) ; ditto

(define my-funs '(f1 f2))

(provide my-funs)
```

...but this gave "Unbound identifier in: f1" when I tried it.

Can I do this? Thanks

**Update:** Just to clarify what I'm trying to do here, I am working my way through Beautiful Racket, and am doing the first tutorial. At the stage where he [defines the expander](https://beautifulracket.com/stacker/the-expander.html), he adds a `handle` function to handle the operators...

```lisp
(define (handle [arg #f])
  (cond
    [(number? arg) (push-stack! arg)]
    [(or (equal? * arg) (equal? + arg))
     (define op-result (arg (pop-stack!) (pop-stack!)))
     (push-stack! op-result)]))
```

But then, in order to make this work, he `provide`s both `+` and `*`...

```lisp
(provide + *)
```

This means that these two operators are hard-coded twice. When adding support for other operators, you'd need to modify the `handle` function and the `provide` call. I am trying to work out if we can define a list of operators, and use that in both, so you'd only need to make one modification to support new operators.

Comment: You're exporting `my-funs`, which identifies a list that contains the *symbols* `f1` and `f2`. (That is, `(car my-fun)` is the symbol `f1`, not a function.) `(provide my-funs)` is not the same as `(provide '(f1 f2))`, which is not the same as `(provide f1 f2)`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for the comment. I'm still new at Racket, so slowly digesting this sort of thing. Is it possible to do what I want to do? Thanks again.

Comment: @molbdnilo Are you able to answer my question? I still don't know if it's possible to provide a list of functions. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there anything else you need for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

You can export a list of functions by using [`filtered-out`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprovide..rkt%29._filtered-out%29%29) and [`begin-for-syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/begin.html?q=begin-for-syntax#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._begin-for-syntax%29%29) (as seen below), but this prevents you from using the list within your code.

##### Exporting a list

```lisp
#lang racket

(module fns racket
  (require racket/provide)
  (define (f1 a) (+ a 1))
  (define (f2 a) (+ a 2))

  (begin-for-syntax
    (define my-funs '(f1 f2)))

  (provide
    (filtered-out
      (λ (name) (and (member (string->symbol name) my-funs) name))
      (all-defined-out))))

(require 'fns)
(display (f1 2))
```

##### How this works

`provide` can take any number of `provide-spec` forms and specifying multiple `provide-spec`s is equivalent to writing multiple `provide` forms. One of the available `provide-spec` forms is `all-defined-out`, which will export all defined symbols in the module (or file if a module isn't explicitly specified).

By requiring `racket/provide`, we get access to helper functions that can transform and operate on `provide-spec` forms; `filtered-out` in particular allows us to run arbitrary code over a `provide-spec` and returns a valid `provide-spec`. (The required [`proc-expr`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/lambda.html) is a function that takes a string (the string value of the exported identifiers) and returns a string or a falsy value. That's why when using `member`, we wrap it in an `and` and return the raw name itself. This could also be accomplished with `findf`: `(λ (name) (findf (λ (n) (equal? (string->symbol name) n)) my-funs))`)

However, this isn't quite enough, as `provide` is executed at "compile time", meaning that our list `my-funs` isn't available yet. To handle that, we need to wrap that definition in `begin-for-syntax`, which makes the binding available at "compile time" as well. But, by moving `my-funs` to "compile time", you lose the ability to use `my-funs` in non-"compile time" code. This means, for instance, you couldn't say `(cond ... [(member arg my-funs) ...])`:

```lisp
(define (handle [arg #f])
  (cond
    [(number? arg) (push-stack! arg)]
    [(member arg my-funs)
              ;; ^--- Error here with "my-funs: unbound identifier"
     (define op-result (arg (pop-stack!) (pop-stack!)))
     (push-stack! op-result)]))
```